# Trying to get property of non-object error in Laravel middleware when passing the route parameters

Tags: routes, laravel-5.3, middleware

I am trying to read a route parameter from a middleware. 
The route is defined as:

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task_id}','TaskController@search')->middleware('test');
```

The error occurs in the middleware that is defined as:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Task;
class test
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    print_r($request->route()->parameter('task_id'));
    /*$result=Task::where('id','=',$id)->get()->count();
    if($result==0)
        return "This id doesn't exist!";

    return $next($request);*/
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the middleware wants to return a redirection, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want with the following:

```
$this->route('task_id');
```

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: Where should I put that? It's not working inside the Middleware at all!

Comment: inside the handle function remove everything and add dd($request) only.
what does you see ?

Comment: yes it produces output. Even if I use dd($request->route('task_id'));

Comment: and also please let me know what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The problem occurs if I remove the dd() function and if I do something like this:

Comment: The problem occurs if I remove the dd() function and if I do something like this: $id=$request->route('task_id');

Comment: I am trying to see if and ID exists, before I send it to the controller.

Comment: Go through this tutorial, make sure to check all steps: https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-laravel-route-parameters-in-middleware

Comment: Your middleware is properly registered?

Comment: of course! 'test' => \App\Http\Middleware\test::class,

Answer (score 0):

use this, where task_id should be the name of your parameter you are looking for

```
$request->route('task_id')
```

Comment: is your middleware is registered ? 
what happens if you dd inside the middleware ? does it dumps anything ?

Comment: it works fine if I use dd() function. I can fetch the value of the variable. But if I use $id=$request->route('task_id'); it produces the same error.

Comment: it works fine with the dd(); If I remove the dd(),it produces the error;

Comment: what do you mean to update? they produce the exact same thing.